# ElasticsearchIllegalStateException[[index.version.created] is not present in the index settings for index with uuid: [null]]

Tags: elasticsearch

I just upgraded my elasticsearch to 1.4.2, and when I try to create an index by

```
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/twitter/tweet/1' -d '{
    "user" : "kimchy",
    "post_date" : "2009-11-15T14:12:12",
    "message" : "trying out Elasticsearch"
}'
```

Then I got an error,

```
{"error":"IndexCreationException[[twitter] failed to create index]; nested: ElasticsearchIllegalStateException[[index.version.created] is not present in the index settings for index with uuid: [null]]; ","status":500}%
```

How should I set the index settings?

Comment: Is the index twitter already created ??

Answer (score 3):

Seems it will be late answer, but you have to add an entry with `index.version.created: %yourversion%` to your Elasticsearch configuration file (**elasticsearch.yml** is default).

For your server version it will be `1040299` constant. You can check the list of this constants at https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/Version.java. Then you need to restart the server.